# Are java exploits based off of the jre used to run the application or the jdk used to compile the code, or both?

Tags: java, security, exploit

I know this question might be kind of broad.  There may be some exceptions.

Suppose I compiled with Java 6 jdk, but than ran with Java 7 jre.   Would the application be vulnerable to Java 6 exploits or java 7 exploits?  Or would it be some combination?

Assuming it is a combination, how do you tell which issues are caused by the jdk compile, and which are caused by the jre?

Comment: I would expect most of the vulnerabilities to be tied to the running environment, seeing as compiler bugs generally result in either valid code not compiling or invalid code compiling but failing with an exception at runtime. But of course your mileage may vary, personally I'd be more worried about third party libraries. (And of course the Java browser plugin.)

Comment: The JRE executes the code so it would be vulnerable to Java7 client exploits. But it could also be vulnerable to Java 6 compiler exploits as Java is compiled into binary code using the JDK 6 compiler. It's a mix of both, either a bad/exploited compiler that flips the wrong bit and/or a JRE that runs that exploited code.

Comment: @biziclop The jdk makes the byte code.  If the byte code/program has some weakness, maybe someone can abuse the program.  That abusive use of a program may not actually use invalid command to the jdk.

Comment: @GiantTree Are the exploits sorted by compile and client exploits?  Do you have a link?

Comment: @GC_ In theory, yes. In practice I wouldn't worry too much about it, there are far bigger attack surfaces around. Your code (and your JRE) has to be pretty damn secure for a possible compiler bug to be the weakest link. But of course it isn't impossible.

Comment: @GC_ I don't know of any list of exploits. I just know how they work in theory.

Comment: @GiantTree So I guess given what your saying, if you compile with 1.6, you have to assume you are vulnerable to all java 1.6 exploits.

Comment: All 1.6 exploits? If you're extra paranoid, then yes. But in reality almost all the known exploits are tied to the JRE. (And a lot more than that to the Java plugin itself.) I think you'd struggle to find a single exploitable compiler bug, let alone on the order of magnitude that is worth exploiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Oracle.  Basically, they confirmed the JRE is what matters, not the JDK.  I don't know of any publically available information to support this, but I did get the information from Oracle, in a help issue.